# Add shipping on subtotal after discount

Tags: magento-1.8, shipping, discount

I want to add freeshipping on subtotal but after discount i already have tried with

```
if ($request->getFreeShipping() 
|| $request->getPackageValueWithDiscount() >= $this->getConfigData('free_shipping_subtotal')) {
    ...
}
```

But this only takes subtotal not and discount did anyone know how can I get subtotal after discount.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as your **collectTotals** order is to calculate discount first then using **$request->getPackageValueWithDiscount()** will be the discounted total.

See **Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address:**

```
 $packageValueWithDiscount = $item
        ? $item->getBaseRowTotal() - $item->getBaseDiscountAmount()
        : $this->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount();
    $request->setPackageValueWithDiscount($packageValueWithDiscount);
```